# Enable bcmath module PHP 7.2 server CLI

Tags: php, command-line-interface, ini, bcmath

I have installed the **php bcmath module for 7.2** via the command:

```
yum install php-bcmath
```

I can see that it's there, but it's not in the php ini file when I check with command `php -i`

**How can I enable this module?**

Server is CentOS 7 running Plesk 17.8.11

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: mayby `sudo phpenmod bcmath` will help?

Comment: Simply get a '-bash: phpenmod: command not found' for this command @NikitaU.